# Finding all children with duplicate columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find duplicates in a table column only if the row is also a child of another table ex:

table 1 columns

```
id
Type
```

table 2 columns

```
id
table1Id
table3Id
```

Sample Data:

```
table 1:
    id    Type
    1      aType
    2      myType
    3      myType
    4      myType
    5      myType
    6      myType

table 2:
    id    table1Id    table3Id
    1        1            1
    2        2            1
    3        4            2
    4        5            1
    5        6            2
```

Results I'd like: (rows in table1 with same Type and table3Id)

```
table1Id  table1Type table3Id
   2        myType     1
   5        myType     1
   4        myType     2
   6        myType     2
```

query I tried:

```
select t1.id as table1Id, t1.type as table1Type, t2.table3Id 
from table1 t1 inner join
    table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.table1Id inner join
    table1 a 
    on t1.Type = a.Type and a.id <> t1.id
where t1.Type = 'myType' ;
```

The above query gives me hundreds of repeats of the same row, with around 500,000 rows returned.

Comment: And why is `id = 1` missing from the results you would like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: because it doesn't have a duplicate entry that is a child of the same table3 row and has the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want pairs of `table3id` and `table1type` that are the same.  Here is a method that returns results in a slightly different format:

```
select t2.table3id, t1.type, group_concat(t1.id) as table1ids
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.table1id
group by t2.table3id, t1.type
having count(*) > 1;
```

This puts the ids with the same value in a list.

Comment: How would I exclude the table1 row with the lowest id? Then I could delete all the duplicate excluding the first

Comment: @rodney757 . . . If you have a question about deleting rows, then you should ask that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
drop table if exists table1;
drop table if exists table2;

create table test_delete.table1 as    
select  1   id  , 'aType' typ union all
select  2      ,'myType' union all
select  3      ,'myType' union all
select  4      ,'myType' union all
select 5      ,'myType' union all
select 6      ,'myType';

create table test_delete.table2 as    

select    1  id     , 1     table1Id     ,  1 table3Id union all
select  2        ,2           , 1 union all
select   3        ,4           , 2 union all
select   4        ,5           , 1 union all
select   5        ,6           , 2;

select * from table1; 

select 
    t1.id, t1.typ, t2.table3Id
from
    table1 t1
        inner join
    table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1Id
where
    t1.typ = 'myType'
order by t2.table3Id;
```

Comment: This query is returning all rows where t1.type = "myType", not just the duplicates